# Meteor: List all collections on the server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am unable to list all the collections created within the Meteor app on the server.

The collections sit... `/root/packages/lib/collectionName.js`

Operations to collectionName succeeds. However, as I have many collections,  I require a function to retrieve all the names of the collections created.

In a server function **after** the collections have been loaded, a method executes the following function;

```
MyCollection = Mongo.Collection.getAll();
console.log(MyCollection);


        [ { name: 'users',
       instance: 
          { _makeNewID: [Function],
            _transform: null,
            _connection: [Object],
            _collection: [Object],
            _name: 'users',
            _driver: [Object],
            _restricted: true,
            _insecure: undefined,
            _validators: [Object],
            _prefix: '/users/' },
        options: undefined },
       { name: 'MeteorToys/Impersonate',
         instance: 
         { _makeNewID: [Function],
         ....
```

The user collection created by Meteor is there. But all the collections created, 3 of which are with Collection2 package do not show.

What am I missing?

What are the implications if I require the child_process library and execute a series of commands.. "meteor mongo"... "db.getCollectionNames()"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all collections on the server, use the RemoteCollectionDriver to access preexisting MongoDB Collections. To implement this server side, you could follow this asynchronous pattern:

```
var shell = function () {
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'),
        future = new Future(),
        db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

    db.collectionNames( 
        function(error, results) {
            if (error) throw new Meteor.Error(500, "failed");
            future.return(results);
        }
    );
    return future.wait();
};
```

Comment: I was using connect to connect to the local db url. This answer is perfect. Thanks chridam!

Comment: Ah, so that's how you access the raw db? Does it act in the same way as `meteor mongo`?

Comment: @corvid Yes, because Meteor is built top of the MongoDB and Meteor is heavily depending on MongoDB at this moment. You can also get raw access to the collection and database objects in the npm MongoDB driver through `rawCollection` and `rawDatabase methods` on `Mongo.Collection`.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski Thank you for noticing the typo :)