# Meteor: Show all collections of a database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I'm creating a Meteor App where the user selects a database & views all its collections. I want to enlist all the databases & their collections that my mongo server currently has in my homepage but I cannot see how that is done. Please help, Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826774/meteor-list-all-collections-on-the-server

Comment: I've created the databases using MongoInternals in the server code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the shell you can list all the databases using

```
db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )
```

Then you can list all the collections with

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Meteor will most likely have a wrapper for these commands.

Comment: Any idea what those wrappers are?